# What is the best way to manage rolling aws credentials to new relic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-rds, newrelic

My aws credentials are getting rotated for one of the roles. This url:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/newrelicrole
```

always gives me the latest credentials for newrelicrole role on aws, I want to be able to populate the environment with the updated access key and secret key to fill [new relic plugin config](https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_aws_cloudwatch_plugin/blob/master/config/template_newrelic_plugin.yml)

What is the best way to go about it, except running a cron job which fetches the response and repopulates the environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are scraping the metadata feed for keys and putting it in a static file, you're doing it wrong- those keys rotate every four hours.

[If you look at line 26 in the plugin config](https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_aws_cloudwatch_plugin/blob/master/config/template_newrelic_plugin.yml#L26), you'll see the answer. Enable this and disable the access/secret key configs.

```
  #Use the following line disable the key checks and enable usage of AWS instance metadata for setting keys
  use_aws_metadata: true
```

Comment: that was wonderful, I just stopped reading the config after I saw the line where we require AWS keys and stopped reading further.